# Download KNIME extensions manually

Tags: knime

My company's firewall doesn't allow the built-in updater to communicate with the Internet to fetch the updates and extensions, and USB drives are disabled by default.

Is there a way to **manually** download extensions such as the Weka integration as a `.zip` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this [file](http://www.knime.org/update/UpdateSite.zip). I have got this link from this site: http://www.knime.org/downloads/update

You might know that the proxy settings can help in installing the extensions (though the antivirus/content filtering might prevent downloading zip/jar files). [This answer](http://tech.knime.org/faq#q24) is probably already seen.